# RabbitMQ on Ubuntu (bionic) installation issue

Tags: ubuntu, installation, rabbitmq, erlang

Follownig instructions under:

[Installing on Debian and Ubuntu](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#erlang-repositories)

1. Add Repository Signing Key:

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rabbitmq/signing-keys/releases/download/2.0/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

2. Enable apt HTTPS Transport:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

3. Add a Source List File: (/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.erlang.list) with content:

```
deb http://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang
```

4. Install Erlang Packages:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y erlang-base \
                        erlang-asn1 erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-ftp erlang-inets \
                        erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-public-key \
                        erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl \
                        erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tftp erlang-tools erlang-xmerl
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package erlang-ftp
E: Unable to locate package erlang-tftp
```

How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I followed the suggestion of **legoscia** and continued with:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server
```

Unfortunately it ended with another portion of console complains.

Then I gave a chance to **Will** and looked at "Quick Start Example" shell snippet:

[Quick Start Example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-bintray-quick-start)

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install curl gnupg -y

curl -fsSL https://github.com/rabbitmq/signing-keys/releases/download/2.0/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list <<EOF
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main
EOF

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing
```

with the above, finally things look promising. Thank you. Both of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The packages `erlang-ftp` and `erlang-tftp` were introduced in Ubuntu 19.04 (disco), and are thus not present in bionic.  Just leave them out of the command; they're not required for RabbitMQ to function.